# Multi Threaded High Performance txt file parsing

Tags: c++, performance, concurrency

**EDIT**

A port of Björn's answer to C++ with further improvements [at bottom](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/235583/212940) achieving up to 2.4GB/s on the reference machine.

---

Text file parsing and processing continues to be a common task. Often it's slow, and can become a performance bottleneck if data is large or many files need to be processed.

**Background**

This is the next stage on from [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/235314/high-performance-txt-file-parsing). As before the ["Yahtzee" programming challenge](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/dv0231/20191111_challenge_381_easy_yahtzee_upper_section/) shall serve as an illustrative example. Follow that link for full details, but the task is basically:

- Read [~1MB file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cosmologicon/beadf49c9fe50a5c2a07ab8d68093bd0/raw/fb5af1a744faf79d64e2a3bb10973e642dc6f7b0/yahtzee-upper-1.txt) with about ~100,000 newline separated ints  (we are using that file repeated x1,000 because we got too fast => ~900MB; see below).
- Group them by hash map. We are using the 3rd party, [`ska::bytell_hash_map`](https://github.com/skarupke/flat_hash_map), instead of `std::unordered_map`, because it is about 2.5x faster.
- Find the group with the largest sum and return that sum.

In the first code review I focused on:

- How to read the file efficiently => conclusion `mmap` (linux specific, see the other question for details and alternatives).
- How to parse efficiently => once we are efficiently reading the file, parsing becomes the bottleneck. The other question progressively moved to stripping the parsing right down to a tight loop incrementing a pointer over the mmap file with minimal checking / branching.

The file format here is very simple. One integer per line terminated with `'\n'`. We are assuming the data is in ASCII and no illegal characters exist; only `[0-9]`.

The test file we used initially [is this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cosmologicon/beadf49c9fe50a5c2a07ab8d68093bd0/raw/fb5af1a744faf79d64e2a3bb10973e642dc6f7b0/yahtzee-upper-1.txt) repeated a 1,000 times with: `for i in {1..1000}; do cat  yahtzee-upper-1.txt >> yahtzee-upper-big.txt ; done`. This produces a file about 900MB in size, but with a very low cardinality (only 791 unique integers), which means the hashmap part of the algorithm is not too much of a bottleneck. See below for the second part of the challenge with a file with higher cardinality.  With such stripped down code and `mmap` we were able to achieve ~540MB/s (1.7seconds for this file) using a single thread.

(All timings are for a i7-2600 Sandy Bridge processor with 16GB of DDR3-1600 and a 500MB/s SSD, **but** note that we ensure that the file is *OS cached* so already in RAM. Hence the 500MB/s is not really relevant.)

**The next level**

In order to go faster still this question / code review focuses on going multi-threaded for the parsing. It turns out that the algorithm is  [Embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) if we chunk the mmap and just let each thread build its own hashmap and then combine them at the end. This last step is not significant (certainly not for the `yahtzee-upper-big.txt` file due to the low cardinality).

Code is at bottom. It can achieve < 400ms for the full (cached)read, parse, hashmap and combine using 8 threads (that CPU has 4 cores + HT). (Note the `os::fs::MemoryMappedFile` class is my own [`RAII` convenience wrapper](https://github.com/oschonrock/toolbelt/blob/master/os/fs.hpp) for `mmap`). Scaling is not bad to 8 threads, but it visibly tails off. (Note that a tight single threaded loop spinning a pointer through the `mmap` takes ~140ms).

```
1 thread:  ~1700ms
4 threads: ~680ms
6 threads: ~437ms
8 threads: ~390ms
```

This is quite good, although I would **welcome feedback on the concurrency  coding / style**.

The real challenge for this approach comes when we use a file with a higher cardinality (ie more unique integers and therefore a much bigger hashmap with more entries).

Here is a small utility to generate a more challenging file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) return 1;

  auto gen = std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()};
  std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> dist(1'000'000, 2'000'000);

  auto file = std::ofstream{argv[1]}; // NOLINT

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 100'000'000; ++i) {
    file << dist(gen) << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

run like this to make ~800MB file with cardinality 1,000,001.

```
./build/bin/yahtzee_gen yahtzee-upper-big2.txt
```

The performance of this file, despite being slightly smaller, is **much** slower: ~2.1s on 8 threads. The single threaded performance is: 4.7seconds showing poor scalability. `perf stat` reports this:

```
 Performance counter stats for 'build/bin/yahtzee_mthr yahtzee-upper-big2.txt':

         14,159.77 msec task-clock                #    6.044 CPUs utilized          
             2,789      context-switches          #    0.197 K/sec                  
                 8      cpu-migrations            #    0.001 K/sec                  
           169,114      page-faults               #    0.012 M/sec                  
    49,300,366,303      cycles                    #    3.482 GHz                      (83.26%)
    44,125,329,192      stalled-cycles-frontend   #   89.50% frontend cycles idle     (83.26%)
    39,070,916,691      stalled-cycles-backend    #   79.25% backend cycles idle      (66.68%)
    16,818,483,760      instructions              #    0.34  insn per cycle         
                                                  #    2.62  stalled cycles per insn  (83.36%)
     2,613,261,878      branches                  #  184.555 M/sec                    (83.47%)
        24,712,823      branch-misses             #    0.95% of all branches          (83.33%)

       2.342779054 seconds time elapsed

      13.755426000 seconds user
       0.412222000 seconds sys
```

**Note** the front and back-end idle cycles. I suspect that this kind of poor scalability can be typical where we are iterating through a large file whilst building up a significant size data structure from the input. A common use case?

**Note**: We attempted CPU pinning (before switching from std::thread to std::async / std::future), but that made little difference.

**Feedback / Ideas Wanted**

- Coding style and technique for the concurrent implementation.
- Ideas / code / tuning suggestions for helping improve the multi-threaded performance of the **high cardinality** file.

And finally here is the code:

```
#include "flat_hash_map/bytell_hash_map.hpp"
#include "os/fs.hpp"
#include <cstdint>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

using uint64 = std::uint64_t;
using map_t  = ska::bytell_hash_map<uint64, uint64>;

std::pair<const char* const, const char* const> from_sv(std::string_view sv) {
  return std::make_pair(sv.data(), sv.data() + sv.size());
}

std::string_view to_sv(const char* const begin, const char* const end) {
  return std::string_view{begin, static_cast<std::size_t>(end - begin)};
}

map_t parse(std::string_view buf) {
  auto map          = map_t{};
  auto [begin, end] = from_sv(buf);
  const char* curr  = begin;
  uint64      val   = 0;
  while (curr != end) {
    if (*curr == '\n') {
      map[val] += val;
      val = 0;
    } else {
      val = val * 10 + (*curr - '0');
    }
    ++curr; // NOLINT
  }
  return map;
}

std::vector<std::string_view> chunk(std::string_view whole, int n_chunks, char delim = '\n') {
  auto [whole_begin, whole_end] = from_sv(whole);
  auto        chunk_size        = std::ptrdiff_t{(whole_end - whole_begin) / n_chunks};
  auto        chunks            = std::vector<std::string_view>{};
  const char* end               = whole_begin;
  for (int i = 0; end != whole_end && i < n_chunks; ++i) {
    const char* begin = end;
    if (i == n_chunks - 1) {
      end = whole_end; // always ensure last chunk goes to the end
    } else {
      end = std::min(begin + chunk_size, whole_end);   // NOLINT std::min for OOB check
      while (end != whole_end && *end != delim) ++end; // NOLINT ensure we have a whole line
      if (end != whole_end) ++end;                     // NOLINT one past the end
    }
    chunks.push_back(to_sv(begin, end));
  }
  return chunks;
}

uint64 yahtzee_upper(const std::string& filename) {
  auto     mfile     = os::fs::MemoryMappedFile{filename};
  unsigned n_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

  auto fut_maps = std::vector<std::future<map_t>>{};
  for (std::string_view chunk: chunk(mfile.get_buffer(), n_threads)) { // NOLINT
    fut_maps.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, parse, chunk));
  }

  uint64 max_total = 0;
  auto   final_map = map_t{};
  for (auto&& fut_map: fut_maps) {
    map_t map = fut_map.get();
    for (auto pair: map) {
      uint64 total = final_map[pair.first] += pair.second;
      if (total > max_total) max_total = total;
    }
  }
  std::cout << final_map.size() << "\n";
  return max_total;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) return 1;
  std::cout << yahtzee_upper(argv[1]) << '\n'; // NOLINT
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about adversarial input? That is, are input files designed to break the hash data structure you are using allowed? Also, would a randomized algorithm be acceptable? One that is right say 99.99% of the time but sometimes wrong?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist 
If you mean ill-formed txt filles with letters or space, then no, I am not focused on that right now. If/when we maximise MT parsing, I can reintroduce some checking. Apart from that, how would you break the hashmap? If you send all unique ints, then sure, it will be slower, but it won't break? Regarding probabilistic estimates, I would not like to go there. The idea for me behind this question is  to learn more techniques about how to write efficient concurrent algorithms. This is already lock free, but of course that does not mean contention free. So that is the focus.

Comment: Not malformed input, [algorithmic complexity attacks](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/hash-table-attack-8e4371fc5261/). You can't break the hashmap, but you likely can trigger worst case performance.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist
OK, I am aware of that, and that's an interesting topic. But for me, in this question, I am assuming this is a "controlled file". Like a CSV database backup or large "world state" game engine data file. Something which we "reasonably trust" and hence why we are prepared to parse and interpret GBs of it.

Comment: There's the risk when pinning a thread to a CPU that some other process will also have a thread pinned to that CPU, causing your thread to take much longer to run since it could be starved for CPU time.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks. In this case in my env, it seems to make no difference. Does the `perf stat` output: "8      cpu-migrations" tell us that these threads are hardly being migrated anyway (the number is very similarly tiny if I comment out the pinning).

Comment: In the real world, the big file isn't buffered in memory before you start processing it, and as you have simple processing, actually reading the file will be the bottleneck, no matter how many threads you use.

Comment: @D.Jurcau That may be, unless we have just written it (!) which is actually quite common. What if the file is already loaded as a string? Also common.   I have to say, stating "in some scenario the bottleneck will be somewhere else", does not really add much to the discussion. The question (and therefore learning point is): "In the stated scenario how do we reduce contention and gain performance?" . Too hard?

Comment: If you just wrote the file, wouldn't that be a domain-specific optimization? You could instead pipe the file writer into the parser and skip a disk file (pipes are still files I guess). Or even not write it as a text file at all, and make the producer produce shared structured data consumable to the consumer process. That should come pretty close to as fast as an in-proc consumer drinking from the firehose.

Comment: @butt
The pipe would be no faster. Disk is not bottleneck if OS cached. Parsing was, now grouping is. Really what has happened on this iteration is that the parsing and (cached) reading is so fast that the "grouping" is everything, so that's where the effort went. That would be no different if you where to "magically acquire" a block of memory already in `uint64_t[]` form  and `reinterpret_cast` it (technically that's UB I think, but it works).

Comment: @butt What is true, is that the 4x improvement which Björn came up with below (and which I ported to C++) is not really about parsing or file reading anymore. So it's arguably "off topic". But that was the bottleneck and you should never optimise anything which is not the bottleneck, because that would be pointless.

Comment: @butt On "files in cache": Among other things, I manage a rack of servers, for my sins. None of those servers ever use their disk, except for: a) writing logs b) writing DB transactions c) booting (which happens about twice per year after upgrades) . After that: everything is in RAM. That may not be typical. But it's a real scenario. And it's fast. So when I want something "fast", I am looking for it to be "fast" assuming that I don't have to consume it through a straw...

Comment: Again I'd be careful of micro-optimizing this particular case. At first glance, a sequence of "page fault => wait for memory => process => page fault new memory => wait for memory => process => ..." appears like it has a ton of stalls where nothing is happening. However, it probably requires the minimal amount of *active* CPU time compared to any alternative. If you saturate a server with this, the server *could* have optimal overall throughput because each process is work-efficient, even if the latency of one task is higher than memory batching.

Comment: In other words, say you want to instead parse 1000 1GB files, or some number of files much greater than the number of processors you have. Is this still a good solution?

Comment: @butt
Sure, that will depend on the actual real work item, background load etc. I know that what we have managed to achieve in these 2 questions is reduce each phase to a reasonable minimum (probably slightly optimised in some ways). If it's cached it runs at ~1.7GB/s on 8 threads if it's not it runs at disk speed (I have tested that, there appears to be no significant "stall / run / stall"). Because each phase is at minimum, it would now be trivial to tune: 1. parsing tolerance 2. Thread number => load 3. data structure => number range for the actual particular use case. etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103282/discussion-between-oliver-schonrock-and-butt).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope you don't mind a pure C solution. For me it is easier to
optimize code without C++ abstractions. But it should be
straightforward to convert it to idiomatic C++ code.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#endif

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Range of numbers, number of numbers and number of parser threads.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#define MIN_VALUE (1 * 1000 * 1000)
#define MAX_VALUE (2 * 1000 * 1000)
#define N_VALUES 400 * 1000 * 1000
#define N_THREADS 8

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Timing functions.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#define NS_TO_S(x)      ((double)(x) / 1000 / 1000 / 1000)

uint64_t
nano_count() {
#ifdef _WIN32
    static double scale_factor;
    static uint64_t hi = 0;
    static uint64_t lo = 0;

    LARGE_INTEGER count;
    BOOL ret = QueryPerformanceCounter(&count);
    if (ret == 0) {
        printf("QueryPerformanceCounter failed.\n");
        abort();
    }
    if (scale_factor == 0.0) {
        LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
        BOOL ret = QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
        if (ret == 0) {
            printf("QueryPerformanceFrequency failed.\n");
            abort();
        }
        scale_factor = (1000000000.0 / frequency.QuadPart);
  }
#ifdef CPU_64
    hi = count.HighPart;
#else
    if (lo > count.LowPart) {
        hi++;
    }
#endif
    lo = count.LowPart;
    return (uint64_t)(((hi << 32) | lo) * scale_factor);
#else
    struct timespec t;
    int ret = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clock_gettime failed.\n");
        abort();
    }
    return (uint64_t)t.tv_sec * 1000000000 + t.tv_nsec;
#endif
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Generate the data file.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
static int
rand_in_range(int lo, int hi) {
    int range = hi - lo;
    int val = (rand() & 0xff) << 16 |
        (rand() & 0xff) << 8 |
        (rand() & 0xff);
    return (val % range) + lo;
}

static void
run_generate(const char *path) {
    srand(1234);
    FILE *f = fopen(path, "wb");
    for (int i = 0; i < N_VALUES; i++) {
        fprintf(f, "%d\n", rand_in_range(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE));
    }
    fclose(f);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Fast number parser using loop unrolling macros.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#define PARSE_FIRST_DIGIT              \
    if (*at >= '0')         {          \
        val = *at++ - '0';             \
    } else {                           \
        goto done;                     \
    }
#define PARSE_NEXT_DIGIT               \
    if (*at >= '0') {                  \
        val = val*10 + *at++ - '0';    \
    } else {                           \
        goto done;                     \
    }

static void
parse_chunk(char *at, const char *end, size_t *accum) {
    uint64_t val = 0;
    while (at < end) {
        // Parse up to 7 digits.
        PARSE_FIRST_DIGIT;
        PARSE_NEXT_DIGIT;
        PARSE_NEXT_DIGIT;
        PARSE_NEXT_DIGIT;
        PARSE_NEXT_DIGIT;
        PARSE_NEXT_DIGIT;
        PARSE_NEXT_DIGIT;
    done:
        #ifdef _WIN32
        InterlockedExchangeAdd64(&accum[val], val);
        #else
        __sync_fetch_and_add(&accum[val], val);
        #endif
        // Skip newline character.
        at++;
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Thread definition
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
typedef struct {
    char *chunk_start;
    char *chunk_end;
    uint64_t *accum;
} parse_chunk_thread_args;

#ifdef _WIN32
static DWORD WINAPI
parse_chunk_thread(LPVOID args) {
    parse_chunk_thread_args *a = (parse_chunk_thread_args *)args;
    parse_chunk(a->chunk_start, a->chunk_end, a->accum);
    return 0;
}
#else
static void*
parse_chunk_thread(void *args) {
    parse_chunk_thread_args *a = (parse_chunk_thread_args *)args;
    parse_chunk(a->chunk_start, a->chunk_end, a->accum);
    return NULL;
}
#endif

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Parse the whole file.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
static bool
run_test(const char *path) {
    uint64_t time_start = nano_count();

    #ifdef _WIN32
    FILE *f = fopen(path, "rb");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    uint64_t n_bytes = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char *buf_start = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * n_bytes);
    char *buf_end = buf_start + n_bytes;
    assert(fread(buf_start, 1, n_bytes, f) == n_bytes);
    fclose(f);
    #else
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    struct stat sb;
    if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    uint64_t n_bytes = sb.st_size;
    char *buf_start = mmap(NULL, n_bytes, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    char *buf_end = buf_start + n_bytes;
    #endif

    uint64_t time_read = nano_count();

    char *chunks[N_THREADS];
    for (int i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++) {
        chunks[i] = buf_start + (n_bytes / N_THREADS) * i;
        if (i > 0) {
            // Adjust the chunks starting points until they reach past
            // a newline.
            while (*chunks[i] != '\n') {
                chunks[i]++;
            }
            chunks[i]++;
        }
    }
    uint64_t *accum = calloc(MAX_VALUE, sizeof(uint64_t));

    #if _WIN32
    HANDLE threads[N_THREADS];
    #else
    pthread_t threads[N_THREADS];
    #endif
    parse_chunk_thread_args args[N_THREADS];
    for (int i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++) {
        char *chunk_start = chunks[i];
        char *chunk_end = buf_end;
        if (i < N_THREADS - 1) {
            chunk_end = chunks[i + 1];
        }
        args[i].chunk_start = chunk_start;
        args[i].chunk_end = chunk_end;
        args[i].accum = accum;
        #if _WIN32
        threads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, parse_chunk_thread,
                                  &args[i], 0, NULL);
        #else
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, parse_chunk_thread, &args[i]);
        #endif
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++) {
        #if _WIN32
        WaitForSingleObject(threads[i], INFINITE);
        #else
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        #endif
    }
    uint64_t max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        uint64_t val = accum[i];
        if (val > max) {
            max = val;
        }
    }
    uint64_t time_parsed = nano_count();

    free(accum);
    #if _WIN32
    free(buf_start);
    #else
    if (munmap(buf_start, n_bytes) == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    #endif

    // Print timings.
    double read_secs = NS_TO_S(time_read - time_start);
    double parse_secs = NS_TO_S(time_parsed - time_read);
    double total_secs = NS_TO_S(time_parsed - time_start);
    printf("Read  : %.3f seconds\n", read_secs);
    printf("Parse : %.3f seconds\n", parse_secs);
    printf("Total : %.3f seconds\n", total_secs);
    printf("-- Max: %zu\n", max);
    return true;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("%s: [generate|test] path\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    char *cmd = argv[1];
    if (strcmp(cmd, "generate") == 0) {
        run_generate(argv[2]);
    } else if (strcmp(cmd, "test") == 0) {
        if (!run_test(argv[2])) {
            printf("Test run failed!\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    } else {
        printf("%s: [generate|test] path\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

On my i7-6700 CPU desktop with 32 GB RAM, my code parses a 3.2 GB file
in about 1.62 seconds and your code takes about eight
seconds. I compile both programs with `-march=native -mtune=native -O3`

The main difference is that I'm using an array shared by all threads
while you are using a hashmap for each thread. That is inefficient
since the range of possible values is only one million. A hashmap
would have the advantage over an array if the range of values was much
larger than the number of values but that is not the case in your
scenario.

The array can be concurrently modified by all threads by using locking
compiler intrinsics:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
InterlockedExchangeAdd64(&accum[val], val);
#else
__sync_fetch_and_add(&accum[val], val);
#endif
```

The intrinsics ensure that the updates are atomic and that threads
don't interfere with each other.

The last difference is

```
#define PARSE_FIRST_DIGIT              \
    if (*at >= '0') {                  \
        val = *at++ - '0';             \
    } else {                           \
        goto done;                     \
    }
#define PARSE_NEXT_DIGIT               \
    if (*at >= '0') {                  \
        val = val*10 + *at++ - '0';    \
    } else {                           \
        goto done;                     \
    }
while (buf < end) {
    // Parse up to 7 digits.
    PARSE_FIRST_DIGIT;
    PARSE_NEXT_DIGIT;
    PARSE_NEXT_DIGIT;
    PARSE_NEXT_DIGIT;
    PARSE_NEXT_DIGIT;
    PARSE_NEXT_DIGIT;
    PARSE_NEXT_DIGIT;
  done:
```

Here I have manually unrolled the parsing loop using macros. It
improves performance by about 100 ms over your formulation when
compiling with gcc.

#### Linux vs. Windows

On my laptop, the code runs a lot faster on Linux than on Windows. On
Windows with an 1 600 MB file and 4 threads:

```
Read  : 1.170 seconds
Parse : 3.119 seconds
Total : 4.289 seconds
-- Max: 498631000
```

Same setup on Linux:

```
Read  : 0.000 seconds
Parse : 2.814 seconds
Total : 2.814 seconds
-- Max: 498631000
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the approach. You are tackling the obvious bottleneck, ie the shared state. I will look into it further. As I see (apart from the manual unrolling) you have done 2 fundamental things: 1. used shared state for summing with atomics, rather than separate + combine   2. switched to different kinds of data structure. They are connected, but fundamentally: 1. is to do with concurrency and 2 is about a universality / efficiency trade-off. ie we could do 2 in a single threaded environment and it would also be faster at the cost being less universal. Agree?

Comment: Correct. 1. I experimented with giving each thread its own array but that seemed slightly slower (and consumed 8 times as much memory). If there are lots of different numbers, contention shouldn't be bad. 2. If you know that the number of *actual* numbers is much smaller than the number of *possible* numbers, then a hashmap is better. For example, if there is only one million unique numbers, but the range is 2^64.

Comment: Firstly: I like your C-style. Nice code. Secondly: I compiled it and my original "big2" file as above runs in ~0.53s on my machine that is about 4x gain over the 8 separate bytell_hashmaps in my code. So well done #2!  Thirdly I translated your idea into c++. Wasn't too hard a good exercise for me, about what you can't do with `std::atomic`. You can't put them in `std::vector`s. So I used a `std::unique_ptr<std::atomic<uint64>>[1'000'001]`. Thirdly you had an "off-by-one" bug in your code for values 1M -> 2M the array needs to be size=1M+1 for the orig file which includes 2M (your file=OK)

Comment: I also experimented with a single, concurrent hashmap: https://github.com/efficient/libcuckoo but this brought only small gains vs single-thread and was slower than the separate hashmaps and certainly slower than yours. The only slightly "unsatisfying" thing about your solution is that it assumes "A LOT" of knowledge about the file. I didn't implement the hand-unrolled-parse, because I felt it assumed too much (my C++ port of your code, is practically the same speed without it). But the assumptions about min/max and therefore map size are critical.... I guess it depends on the real scenario.

Comment: BTW the distribution of numbers and therefore concurrent access to the array is such that there is almost zero contention on the atomics. How do I know? Before I worked out how to coax the atomics out of c++ abstractions, I ran it without. Always gave the correct answer. So the chance of the clash, ie the atomic having to retry, is very very small.

Comment: BTW, my c++ version allocates half the memory 1M+1 vals, yours allocates 2M. Neither is better, it's a choice...

Comment: giving your `#ifdef _WIN32`  I prsume you ran this on windows (as well?). How did the performance compare? What about the non`mmap` file load? -- which I see you are timing separately.

Comment: found another 33% gain + info on fast SSDs. See EDIT below.

Comment: @OliverSchonrock Added timings. Windows doesn't have anything like mmap so it's hard to compare.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-a-file-mapping-object

Comment: Yes, but that's not faster than reading files the normal way.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist Thanks for timings. Only a 10% diff between Windows and Linux really on the parse. We can't compare read. Uses a completely different mechanism. For windows to have a chance there you would have to do producer/consumer or double buffering (kind of the same thing), or similar.  Have you tried the 32bit tweak from below?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist Actually you read the whole file in Windows right? So that's actually giving windows an advantage for the next stage. I found that mmap is slower than a full pre-read into a buffer (even when file is OS cached), by about 70ms.

Comment: Yep, I incorporated your changes, but was to lazy to update the answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

C++ port of [Björn's code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/235570/212940) using a single large array instead of one hashmap per thread. Björn's C code is very nice, but this question was tagged C++ so i thought it was worth showing that too. The changes from my code above are very small:

- Using std::thread instead of std::async, because we don't need to return anything
- Use a `std::unique_ptr` of `std::atomic<uint64_t>[1'000'001]` as the central datastructure and update with `.fetch_add()`  (`std::vector` doesn't like atomics without writing wrappers). Note that Björn's `array` is 2M entries and mine is 1M+1, because I subtract `min_val` from key.
- the zero initialisation of the array was slightly tricky to find the right syntax for. can't do it with `make_unique` until we get `make_unique_init` in c++20 so used empty brace initialisation instead, see code. --- **EDIT**: this is incorrect. It's not complicated. I proved that the array is always zero initialised. Both with [make_unique](https://godbolt.org/z/aB7eJr), and with [new[]{}](https://godbolt.org/z/Cs_ENk)  and got a detailed explanation of [the standardese here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/eomwv2/why_make_unique_default_init_stdsize_t_size/). So I have changed the code to the more idiomatic `make_unique<>`.
- I didn't include Björn's hand-unrolling of the parsing. I tried limiting the loop iterations to 7, and as soon as I did that, the compiler automatically unrolled it for me. But I felt this was too restrictive on the file format and didn't provide any measurable performance benefit.

For discussion of the prons/cons of this approach see comments under Björn's answer.

Performance of this code on the `yahtzee-upper-big2.txt` (800MB of 100M 7digit ints with cardinality 1M+1) is ~0.55s on my machine. This is a 4x speedup against the original "1x bytell_hash_map per thread" approach at top. Putting it another way this is parsing ~1.7GB/s which is a fair clip on this old machine.

The obvious downside is that it makes assumptions about the *range* of ints in the input file (they must be min=1M and max=2M inclusive).

Björn put it well when he said in comments above: The global atomic array works very well when we have a relatively small range but many numbers. Whereas when we have a very large range (worst case 2^64) and not so many unique numbers (eg the original, low cardinality, "-big" file), then a hash map per thread is fastest.

**EDIT**: I changed the code to use `std::unit32_t` as the main value type in the array. Then just count each value and multiply during the final loop. This optimisation was suggested by someone else, in the previous question, but it never made a measurable difference for me. However, now that this array is central to the performance, particularly whether this array can fit in L3 cache, should make a bigger difference. At 1M * 4bytes => 4MB, it just about might and sure enough, I got a 33% performance gain. The "big2" file now runs in ~350ms, which is about 2.4GB/s.

When you have a windfall, you should treat yourself just a little, so I reintroduced *some* parsing checks. ie the range of the integers is now checked, so we don't access out of bounds memory for UB, and the range of characters is strictly limited to `[0-9\n]`. Performance is hardly affected by these "never taken" branches thanks to the CPU's branch predictor.

On the subject of: "Is this realistic? Why are you doing it cached? The disk will always be the bottleneck.": I did some quick shopping and it seems that, even as of Q4 2017, there are NVMe SSDs which do sequential reads [at a blistering 1800MB/s](https://ssd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/375784/INTEL-SSDPED1D480GA). So it seems we need to work quite hard to stay ahead of these devices.

```
#include "os/fs.hpp"
#include <cstdint>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

using val_t = std::uint32_t;

constexpr val_t      min_val  = 1'000'000;
constexpr val_t      max_val  = 2'000'000;
constexpr std::size_t map_size = max_val - min_val + 1;

std::pair<const char* const, const char* const> from_sv(std::string_view sv) {
  return std::make_pair(sv.data(), sv.data() + sv.size());
}

std::string_view to_sv(const char* const begin, const char* const end) {
  return std::string_view{begin, static_cast<std::size_t>(end - begin)};
}

void parse(std::string_view buf, std::atomic<val_t> map[]) {
  auto [begin, end] = from_sv(buf);
  const char* curr  = begin;
  val_t      val   = 0;
  while (curr != end) {
    if (*curr == '\n') {
      assert(min_val <= val && val <= max_val);
      map[val - min_val].fetch_add(1); // NOLINT
      val = 0;
    } else if ('0' <= *curr && *curr <= '9') {
      val = val * 10 + (*curr - '0');
    }
    ++curr; // NOLINT
  }
}

std::vector<std::string_view> chunk(std::string_view whole, int n_chunks, char delim = '\n') {
  auto [whole_begin, whole_end] = from_sv(whole);
  auto        chunk_size        = std::ptrdiff_t{(whole_end - whole_begin) / n_chunks};
  auto        chunks            = std::vector<std::string_view>{};
  const char* end               = whole_begin;
  for (int i = 0; end != whole_end && i < n_chunks; ++i) {
    const char* begin = end;
    if (i == n_chunks - 1) {
      end = whole_end; // always ensure last chunk goes to the end
    } else {
      end = std::min(begin + chunk_size, whole_end);   // NOLINT std::min for OOB check
      while (end != whole_end && *end != delim) ++end; // NOLINT ensure we have a whole line
      if (end != whole_end) ++end;                     // NOLINT one past the end
    }
    chunks.push_back(to_sv(begin, end));
  }
  return chunks;
}

val_t yahtzee_upper(const std::string& filename) {
  auto     mfile     = os::fs::MemoryMappedFile{filename};
  unsigned n_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  // zero initialised via the empty {} and that's why we didn't use std::make_unique
  auto map = std::make_unique<std::atomic<val_t>[]>(map_size);
  auto     threads   = std::vector<std::thread>{};

  for (std::string_view chunk: chunk(mfile.get_buffer(), n_threads)) // NOLINT
    threads.emplace_back(parse, chunk, map.get());

  for (auto& t: threads) t.join();

  std::uint64_t max_total = 0;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < map_size; ++i) {
    std::uint64_t s = map[i].load() * (i + min_val);
    if (s > max_total) max_total = s;
  }
  return max_total;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) return 1;
  std::cout << yahtzee_upper(argv[1]) << '\n'; // NOLINT
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One performance idea: Do not use branching (if possible by any trick). It is possible to parse text without branching. Have a look at 1BRC ([java code base](https://github.com/gunnarmorling/1brc) for inspiration, but there is also C, rust, ...) or at [json parsing](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/simdjson-parser/).

PS: Evaluating code readability and maintainability when code is optimized for bare performance will show, how unreadable given code is. For example [famous comment "what the fuck?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) in video game.

PS2: Reading of book like [algorithmica](https://en.algorithmica.org/hpc/) can be refreshing and full of knowledge also for coders without skill to write such a performant code.